# KeyUp event works in first winform, but not in second, why?

Tags: vb.net, events

I have a winform program where I am trying to include PF functionality in tandem with button/mouse-click functionality.   On the first screen that opens in the application, the keyup event works.   I changed the KeyPreview property to True and wrote the following code:

```
Private Sub Vehicle_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then
        CarrierOn = True
        Call Display_CarrierDetail_Screen()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F9 Then
        Call Display_History_Screen()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F6 Then
        Call Display_County_Screen()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
        Call Instant_Observation("Vehicle")
    End If

End Sub
```

The above works.

However, on opening the second form, I wrote very similar code, also changed that form's keypreview property to True, and tested the PF key - nothing happens.

Why would it work on the first form, but not on the second?   The second does have the focus when I am pressing the PF key.

Thank you, laurie

Comment: What the heck is the "PF" key?  Don't forget to set KeyPreview = true again.  Overriding the ProcessCmdKey() method is the better solution.

Comment: @nobugz: PF key is an obsolete term for a function key.

Comment: Thank you.   I figured out the ProcessCmdKey() method, and it worked great.   And I am obsolete, I apologize for that.   I was talking about function keys.